# python Formatting Code from a list

Tags: python

So I have a list of words and I want to format it to display a certain way

```
 ["car", "dinosaur", "cat", "Rat"]
```

This is an example of the list. Essentially, i want to print out the elements of the List with a number 1 next to them. The Formatting comes in where I want to space it by the largest word.

```
dinosaur 1
car      1
cat      1
Rat      1
```

So you can see how the 1 appears after the longest word. The issue is how do i format this by from a list. The code I am using right is by looping over the list of words to find the longest word then adding spaces to each of the smaller words in order to be the same length as the largest word. Any easier way of doing it?

Comment: Since 2.6 you can also use the new format method, for example:

x = '{} {}'.format(*s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just find the longest word and format the output:

```
max_length = len(max(words, key=len))
for word in words:
    print "{0:{1}s} 1".format(word, max_length)
```

Comment: Wow didn't even think of that, Thanks

Comment: Note that this recursive format string gives a syntax error (Python 3.4).

Comment: @HughBothwell: Yes, in Python 3 `print` is a function.

Comment: @Daniel: (d'oh!) My mistake...

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
# find longest word
word_length = max(len(word) for word in words)

# create a format string
format_str = "{{:{}s}} 1".format(word_length)

# use the format string
for word in words:
    print(format_str.format(word))
```